# Can I create new custom dialogs with BlueSky Statistics?

Tags: dialog

I want to create a dialog for spatial analysis, I need access to the custom dialog builder, is it open source?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Dialog Designer from the website https://www.blueskystatistics.com/. It is free and open source.